# Why there are different method's argument names of openGL in netbeans and idea?

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, intellij-idea

I have a problem.
In netbeans, the names of arguments are showed correctly, as you can see in the link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjMOI.jpg

But IntelliJ idea shows me just some native names, like int i, int i1 and so on, as you can see below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxLBO.jpg

Please, how can I fix that?

Comment: Are you using different OpenGL bindings between the two projects?

Comment: I have already fixed this problem. I went to the Project structure > Libraries and there I added whole lib folder. imgur.com/7PQSS5P